# deployment tool with feature branches

Tags: deployment, git

I would like to use a deployment tool that allows me to deploy feature branches, i.e., I would like to deploy every branch of my Git repository.

In all deployment tools (e.g., [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), [Go](http://www.go.cd/), [DeployBot](http://deploybot.com/),...) that I've checked so far, you can only statically select one branch. While there can of course be several pipelines with different branches, I have seen nothing yet that allows dynamic deployment of all branches.

Maybe I'm thinking of the problem in the wrong terms. Any hints here?

Comment: Why? What is the problem you're trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: I'd like to see my feature branches (e.g., features for a web platform) in action before merging them into master.

Answer (score 0):

The Release Management tool we have developed allows you to deploy from any branch of your Git repository. Please check out more at https://syncrelease.com

Please let me know if you want to see the demo. I am now looking for beta testers for trying our tool for free.